# MS Dynamics Webservice

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am using MS Dynamics CRM 4 and requesting contacts in a list using the Web Service. My only filter I am applying is listname.

The problem is that in Dynamics the list has 3000 members but the web service is only returning 2200.

Anyone know why there is a difference? All records are of the same type and I have eliminated those that are not active.

---

Looking into this further it seems that when you look at the marketing list in dynamics the contact appears. However if you open the contact record the marketing list does not appear on the contact record.

Comment: Could you please provide code that you use to retrieve data from CRM?

Answer (score 0):

There are restrictions on count of records can be returned with single request and you should avoid situation downloading large amount with single request.

I found sample of code for CRM 2011, you should have something like this
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80c1eb70-81db-49d4-8dc8-4cd04f4ae37e/retrive-more-than-5000-records-from-crm-2011-using-web-service-and-c?forum=crmdevelopment